# Polynomial approximation algorithm for set cover with assumption

Tags: approximation-algorithms, set-cover

We want to cover $n$ elements with some sets from $S_1, …, S_m$ (classical set cover).

We furthermore suppose that any element belongs to at least $k$ sets and want to find a set cover with cardinal at most $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{m \cdot log(n)}{k}\right)$.

For $k=1$, the classical greedy algorithm works, but after that I'm stuck.

Comment: Is this a home work question? If not, what is the motivation or context?

Comment: @ChandraChekuri It is an exercise I found interesting. I spent 1 hour yesterday trying randomized algorithms, but the greedy worked at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer.

I'm going to prove the greedy algorithm yields the correct answer.

Count the number of membership relationships. There are at least $n\cdot k$, so one set must contain more than $\frac{n\cdot k}m$ elements.

After one step of greedy algorithm, there are less than $n_1 = n - \frac{n\cdot k}m = n \left(1 - \frac km\right)$ elements left.

At the second step we remove at least $n_1(1-\frac{k}{m-1})$.

We are guaranteed to terminate when $n~\Pi_{i=0}^j \left( 1-\frac{k}{m-i}\right) < 1$, ie $\log(n) + \sum_{i=0}^j \log\left(1-\frac{k}{m-i}\right) < 0$.

Since $\log(1-x) < -x$, $\log(n) < \sum_{i=0}^j \frac{k}{m-i}$ is sufficient.

We are looking for the smallest $j$ such that:

$ m-j < \exp(\log(m) - \frac{\log(n)}{k}) = \frac{m}{n^\frac1k}$

$\Longleftrightarrow j > m\left(1-\frac{1}{n^\frac1k}\right) = m\left(1-\frac{1}{\exp(\frac{log(n)}{k}}\right)$

Now, $1-\frac{1}{\exp(x)} ≤ x$ by convexity, hence $j > \frac{m \log(n)}{k}$ is sufficient.

Comment: Since you found the answer here is another way to do it via the well-known LP relaxation for Set Cover. Since each element is in at least k sets one can find a feasible fractional solution of value at most $m/k$ by choosing each set to an extent of $1/k$. Then another standard result is that Greedy gives a solution of cost at most $OPT_{LP} H_p$ where $OPT_{LP}$ is the value of the optimum LP solution and $H_p$ is the $p$'th harmonic number where $p$ is the maximum set size. Since $p \le n$ and we have seen that $OPT_{LP} \le m/k$ the result follows.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Thank you very much. "Then another standard result is that Greedy gives a solution of cost at most $OPT_{LP}H_p$" do you have a source / name?

Comment: @Labo first chapter of Williamson and Shmoys